# Play sound as a Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, audio, safari

Is it possible to play sound as a Safari Extension? Simple javascript isn't working:

```
var audio = new Audio("http://cl.ly/KdCk/download/review-time.mp3"); 
audio.play();
```

Comment: It works for me on Safari 6.0.1, which version do you use?

Comment: Also 6.0.1. It works for me in a simple html file, but not in an extension. Strange... :/ Maybe Safari Extensions can't play audio?

Comment: Any solution on this? I have the same problem.